# How to enable the Annotate option in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Here the Annotate option is not enabled.

Comment: Is your project under version control? You can enable version control integration in Preferences | Version Control.

Answer (score 0):

Your project should be under a version control system (GIT, SVN, etc).

See: [JetBrains site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-annotations.html)

> Annotation is a form of file presentation that shows detailed information for each line of code. In particular, for each line you can see the version from which this line originated, the user ID of the person who committed this line, and the commit date. The annotated view helps you find out who did what and when, and trace back the changes.
>
> Annotating lines of code is available for ClearCase, TFS, Mercurial, Git, CVS, Perforce and Subversion.